# Mobile redirect but not when coming from Mobile site

Tags: javascript

i have this script and it works fine. I have it on the Desktop page and when a user enters it they get a question to be redirected to mobile page, this works fine. But i then have on the mobile page a link back to Desktop page, but when this link is clicked and the user gets to the Desktop page they will get the quetsion again. So my question is. Is there a way to let the Desktop page know that the user have clicked the link in Mobile page and if so do not show the Question again?
Thank you.

The code i have now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isMobile = (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && confirm('Realy?'));
if (isMobile)
{
   location.replace("mobile_site.html");
}  
</script>
```

So i also have this code. Any one know how to combind my first script with this one? Thank you.

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
    !window.location.href.contains("#redirected") ) {
window.location = "my_mobile_page.html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just check that the referrer is not your mobile page - if a visitor comes to your desktop page from your mobile page, don't re-direct.

Comment: Don't chnage the title to solved, select an answer.

Comment: sideroxylon - That doesn't work if the user manually switched, and then clicked a link.

Comment: Don't chnage the title to solved, select an answer. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - only re-direct to your mobile site if the user device `isMobile` and if the user has not just linked from that mobile site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var referrer = document.referrer;
  var isMobile = (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && confirm('Realy?'));
  if (isMobile && referrer != 'mobile_site.html')
    {
     location.replace("mobile_site.html");
    }  
</script>
```

EDIT:  Revised code to remove confirmation.  If the user's device is mobile, and the referrer is not the mobile site, the confirmation prompt will display.  If the user accepts it, the re-direction will be triggered.  If the user is returning from the mobile site, the confirmation will not be shown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var referrer = document.referrer;
      if (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && referrer != 'mobile_site.html')
        {
        var r = confirm("Really");
            if (r == true) {
                location.replace("mobile_site.html");
            }  else {
                stop;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hello, This works almost :). I still get the question "Realy?" when i in mobile site click the link to Desktop page. But if i click OK i don not get redirected and this is correct but i also dont whant the Question.

Comment: Please see edit above.  I think this solves your problem.  Sorry, I overlooked that part before.